# Mac OS X - macports - Warning: No index(es) found! Have you synced your source indexes?

Tags: mac, sync, macports

I'm trying to setup an Android build environment for Android. I'm following [these instructions](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

However, after the installation of MacPorts I'm not able to install the environment.

Following the instructions I launched this command:

```
sudo port install gmake libsdl git-core gnupg
```

and I received this message:

```
Warning: No index(es) found! Have you synced your source indexes?
Error: Port gmake not found
```

Now, I tried the selfupdate command but the connection timed-out. I tried the different solutions that I found in the MacPort FAQ but I'm not able to connect to SVN. The connection works fine, if I ping a website from the terminal there is no problem.

Comment: It's not `self update` - it's `selfupdate` - try `sudo port -d selfupdate` - focus on getting this step to work

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried but I have this error: rsync:                failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]

Comment: It seems that there is no connection but if I ping other pages works fine

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have an old version of macports - try getting the latest version from http://www.macports.org/ and start again

Comment: I checked my version and is the latest one. I installed it using MacPorts-1-2.9.2.pkg and I don't understand why the rsync fails to connect to rysing.macports.org

Comment: @benza: does the first part work, e.g. when I do a selfupdate I get: `--->  Updating the ports tree
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s)
Synchronizing local ports tree from http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz
No updates for http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/base
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync` - do you get that far ?

Comment: @PaulR no, I have this: --->  Updating the ports tree
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s) Synchronizing local ports tree from http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz
Warning: Cannot check if http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz was updated, (Timeout was reached) Error: Fetching http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz failed (couldn't connect to host) DEBUG: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed while executing "macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated" Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Couldn't sync the ports tree

Comment: @benza: weird - looks like a connectivity issue, or maybe the permissions are wrong on the directory where macports needs to store the ports tree data file `~/.macports` ?

Comment: I don't have the folder ~/.macports but with sudo I suppose that there are not issues about permission (or am I wrong).
Could be a connectivity issue but I don't know how to be sure about that. If I ping the same address there is not problem.

Comment: and for the SVN I have this error: svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk': could not connect to server (http://svn.macports.org)

Comment: @benza Try to `wget` or `curl` that URL from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a firewall issue?  If you have a proxy server, you might try setting up rsync to work with it.  For example:

```
export RSYNC_PROXY=myproxy.domain.com:80
sudo -E port selfupdate
```

The -E option preserves the user environment of the sudo-ing user.

Hope this helps -- it worked for me, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind a firewall, you'll need to open port 873 for rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo port -d sync`.

It uses svn whereas selfupdate uses rsync. I got it from this thread:
http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2007-July/004725.html